# TikZ calculate in/out-angle from nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two pairs of nodes that are grouped by a brace, i.e. a path with brace-decoration. I want to draw an arrow from the first brace to the second, leaving from and arriving at the respective brace perpendicularly. This is what I have tried:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.45cm,y=.4cm, baseline=(Fb.base),every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]
        \node at (0,0) {$L(ts)$};
        \node at (2,0) {$L(tsut)$};
        \node at (4,0) {$L(tu)$};
        \node at (2,1) {$L(t)$};
        \node at (2,-1) {$L(tsu)$};
        \node (Aa) at (6,0) {$L(tsu)$};
        \node (Ab) at (6,1) {$L(ts)$};
        \draw[decoration={brace}, decorate] ($(Aa)+(1,1.4)$) to node(Pa){} ($(Ab)+(1,-1.4)$);
        %
        \node (Ba) at (10,0) {$L(ts)$};
        \node at (12,0) {$L(tsut)$};
        \node at (14,0) {$L(tu)$};
        \node at (12,1) {$L(t)$};
        \node (Bb) at (12,-1) {$L(tsu)$};
        \node at (16,0) {$L(tsu)$};
        \node at (16,1) {$L(ts)$};
        \draw[decoration={brace, mirror}, decorate] ($(Ba)-(1,-.0)$) to node(Pb){} ($(Bb)-(0.7,.3)$);
        \draw[->] (Pa) to[out=0,in=235] (Pb);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

where the last `draw` produces the desired path. However, the `in`-angle is set by hand, but you can see that it is not perpendicular. How can I make TikZ compute the required angle automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate it with the `let` syntax from the `calc` library. I added two helper coordinates at the start and end of the brace.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.45cm,y=.4cm, every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}]
        \node at (0,0) {$L(ts)$};
        \node at (2,0) {$L(tsut)$};
        \node at (4,0) {$L(tu)$};
        \node at (2,1) {$L(t)$};
        \node at (2,-1) {$L(tsu)$};
        \node (Aa) at (6,0) {$L(tsu)$};
        \node (Ab) at (6,1) {$L(ts)$};
        \draw[decoration={brace}, decorate] ($(Aa)+(1,1.4)$) to node(Pa){} ($(Ab)+(1,-1.4)$);
        %
        \node (Ba) at (10,0) {$L(ts)$};
        \node at (12,0) {$L(tsut)$};
        \node at (14,0) {$L(tu)$};
        \node at (12,1) {$L(t)$};
        \node (Bb) at (12,-1) {$L(tsu)$};
        \node at (16,0) {$L(tsu)$};
        \node at (16,1) {$L(ts)$};
        \draw[decoration={brace, mirror}, decorate] ($(Ba)-(1,-.0)$) coordinate (c1) to node(Pb){} ($(Bb)-(0.7,.3)$) coordinate (c2);
        \draw[->] 
         let
         \p1=(c1),\p2=(c2),\n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)}
         in
        (Pa) to[out=0,in=\n1-90] (Pb);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```